# Issue with passing UIViewcontroller carrying delegate as parameter to swift function

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8

```
class func invite(_cntrl : UIViewController) 
{
  // code to open mail composer sheet
}
```

this method needs to accept controllers which conforms to **`MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate`**.

currently it gives **error** :

```
Type 'UIViewController' does not conform to protocol 
'MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate'
```

how to pass uiviewconroller conforms `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` ?

something like :

```
class func invite(_cntrl : UIViewController<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>)
{
   // code to open mail composer sheet
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class conforming to protocol as function parameter in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051396/class-conforming-to-protocol-as-function-parameter-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you set the parameter type to MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate it accepts that.

so your function would be:

```
class func invite(_cntrl : MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate)
```

As found in the Protocols as Types in the [Swift Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-XID_402)

EDIT:

Upon further clarification, as you want to be able to pass through a subclass of UIViewController that also conforms to the MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, it appears that extending the UIViewController class is the best way to go. (These are like ObjC categories.

e.g.

```
extension UIViewController : MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate
{
  optional func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController!,
            didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult,
                          error error: NSError!)
  {
     self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(flag:true, completion:nil); 
  }
}
```

Comment: If i do so, I won't be able to write _cntrl.presentViewController(mailComposer!, animated: true, completion: nil) to present sheet

Comment: cast it to a UIViewController or to a subclass of UIViewController that also implements the Delegate?

Comment: can not cast to particular subclass of controller as multiple subclasses likely to call this method. also can not cast to UIViewController, gives another error which is obvious one.

Comment: Sorry, my brain has finally decided to work.

There seems there are two ways of handling this.

You can either extend the UIViewController class to conform to the MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate which I would suggest.

Or use generics, but there seems to be no obvious way of using a generic that is a subclass and conforms to a protocol, which you need in this case to be a subclass of UIViewController and conform to the MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate

Answer (score 0):

I don't know an exact solution. But as an alternative if you want to check whether an object conforms to that particular protocol or not using the `is` keyword (also can use `as`)
In this case it'll look like:

```
class func invite(_cntrl : UIViewController)
{
    if _cntrl is MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate
    {
        println("Confirms to protocol")
    }
    else
    {
        println("Not confirm")
    }
}
```

This approach is mentioned in [**Checking for Protocol Conformance**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-XID_426)

> You can use the `is` and `as` operators described in Type Casting to check
>   for protocol conformance, and to cast to a specific protocol. Checking
>   for and casting to a protocol follows exactly the same syntax as
>   checking for and casting to a type:
>
> The `is` operator returns `true` if an instance conforms to a protocol and returns `false` if it does not.
>
> The `as?` version of the downcast operator returns an optional value of the protocol’s type, and this value is `nil` if the instance does not conform to that protocol.
>
> The as version of the downcast operator forces the downcast to the protocol type and triggers a runtime error if the downcast does not succeed.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3 you can do this

```
class func invite(_cntrl : MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate) 
{
   // code to open mail composer sheet
   // You can cast it to a UIViewController subclass if you need it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like,

```
func setDelegate<T : UIViewController>(controller: T) where T: YourDelegateName{
    delegate = controller
}
```