# UIViewController that implements protocol as an argument in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

in my application I want to write function that takes as an parameter UIViewController that implements some protocol. In objective-c I could accomplish this by writing:

```
-(void)someFunction:(UIViewContoller<MyProtocol> *controller);
```

How can I create similar function in Swift?

Comment: Have you tried some like: `func someFunction(controller: theProtocol) -> Void`?

Comment: Of course, but in this situation controller is only that conforms only to theProtocol it isn't UIViewController so you cannot call any method that belongs to UIViewController.

Comment: You're right MichalMoskala. I made a simple search and I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051396/class-conforming-to-protocol-as-function-parameter-in-swift. Try searching before asking, it is better for all the community user2561739

Comment: Thank you very much! I made some searching before asking but didn't find that, my mistake. Answer my question so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried some like this?:

```
func someFunction(controller: theProtocol) -> Void
```

**Edit:**

You're right MichalMoskala. I made a simple search and I found this: [Class conforming to protocol as function parameter in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051396/class-conforming-to-protocol-as-function-parameter-in-swift). Try searching before asking, it is better for all the community.