# Checking for class and conformance to a protocol

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I'm trying to create a method that takes a view controller that also conforms to a protocol. In objective C, that would look something like the following:

```
- (void)myMethod:(UIViewController<MyProtocol> *)viewController
```

but I can't figure out a way to check for both the class type and protocol conformance simultaneously. I could set the function signature to verify half and then check for the second part within the function sort of like:

```
func myMethod(myObject: MyProtocol) {
    if myObject is UIViewController {
        // Do something with it
    } else {
        // Handle the unexpected type
    }
}
```

That feels like there is a lot of extra checks and possibility for human error. Is there a way to check for both the class type and the protocol conformity in the method signature? Alternatively, I could create a base class that inherits from UIViewController and conforms to the protocol, but that adds extra cruft that I'd like to avoid if possible. Thoughts on how this can be approached?

Comment: does this answer your query? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051396/class-conforming-to-protocol-as-function-parameter-in-swift

Comment: Huzzah! It does. Thanks!