# Class as function parameter in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

In my app there are many classes for different ViewControllers.
I am searching way to give class name as function parameter so i can use it in function.

Example

```
func myFunc (var1: String, var2 : Int, var3 : myClass) {
 var example = myClass();
 example.name = var1;
 example.age = var2;
}
```

i saw this thread [Class conforming to protocol as function parameter in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051396/class-conforming-to-protocol-as-function-parameter-in-swift) but i didn't understand how can i solve my problem with it.

Comment: Why do you want to pass the class as the function parameter? Cannot you pass a class instance instead?

Comment: Agree with @MarioZannone , your problem should be solved using inheritance and passing the instance variable to the controller

Comment: can you show me example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without the need to pass an instance of your view controller:

```
import Cocoa

protocol MyViewControllerType : class {
    var name : String { get set }
    var age : Int { get set }
}

class FirstViewController : NSViewController, MyViewControllerType {
    var name = ""
    var age = 0
}

class SecondViewController : NSViewController, MyViewControllerType {
    var name = ""
    var age = 0
}

func myFunc<VC : NSViewController where VC : MyViewControllerType>(viewControllerType: VC.Type, name: String, age: Int) -> VC {
    let viewController = VC()
    viewController.name = name
    viewController.age = age
    return viewController
}

let first = myFunc(FirstViewController.self, name: "Bob", age: 20)
let second = myFunc(SecondViewController.self, name: "Paul", age: 30)
```