# Generic parameter type 'T' cannot be inferred

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I'm getting an error from this code 'generic parameter type 'T' cannot be inferred'.

```
public func userTappedView(headerFooterView: CollapsableTableViewSectionHeaderProtocol, atPoint location:CGPoint) {

        if let tableView = self.collapsableTableView() {

            //Error here
            let value = sectionForUserSelectionInTableView(tableView, atTouchLocation: location, inView: headerFooterView)
            ...
        }
    ...
}


func sectionForUserSelectionInTableView<T: UITableViewHeaderFooterView where T: CollapsableTableViewSectionHeaderProtocol>(tableView: UITableView, atTouchLocation location:CGPoint, inView view: T) -> NSNumber? {
    ...
}
```

Comment: You're passing a CollapsableTableViewSectionHeaderProtocol to a method that requires a UITableViewHeaderFooterView.  Any class could implement that protocol; therefore, the compiler cannot infer that the object you are passing is a UITableViewHeaderFooterView subclass.

Comment: How do I ensure that the subclass of UITableViewHeaderFooterView  conforms to the protocol CollapsableTableViewSectionHeaderProtocol ?

Comment: You can cast it if you know that it will be a UITableViewHeaderFooterView, or change the definition of userTappedView to require a UITableViewHeaderFooterView.

Comment: There must be another way to handle this.

Comment: When userTappedView is called, it is given a CollapsableTableViewSectionHeaderProtocol.  There is not enough information in this type to know that it is a UITableViewHeaderFooterView.  You either need to pass that information to the userTappedView method via the parameter type, or cast it.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: Try removing the generic type T and changing the parameter's type to CollapsableTableViewSectionHeaderProtocol.

Comment: That solves my problem. Still curious to know why this approach works for this guy though http://stackoverflow.com/a/24051850/1951992

Comment: With a class type, the compiler can determine whether or not if conforms to a protocol by looking at its definition.  On the other hand, a protocol type could be (literally) any class that conforms to that protocol, and as such the compiler cannot determine whether or not it is a subclass of a particular class.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I do understand your question that is to ensure the subclass of UITableViewHeaderFooterView conforms to the protocol CollapsableTableViewSectionHeaderProtocol.

If my assumption is correct, you can do something like this:

```
//// Define a protocol
protocol CollapsableTableViewSectionHeaderProtocol {
    func sectionForUserSelectionInTableView(tableView: UITableView, atTouchLocation location:CGPoint, inView view: T) -> NSNumber?
}

class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    internal func userTappedView(headerFooterView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView, atPoint location:CGPoint) {
        //// Call CollapsableTableViewSectionHeaderProtocol method
        let value = headerFooterView.sectionForUserSelectionInTableView(self.tableView, atTouchLocation: location, inView: headerFooterView)
        print(value)
    }
}

//// Implement CollapsableTableViewSectionHeaderProtocol for UITableViewHeaderFooterView via extension
extension UITableViewHeaderFooterView: CollapsableTableViewSectionHeaderProtocol {
    func sectionForUserSelectionInTableView(tableView: UITableView, atTouchLocation location:CGPoint, inView view: T) -> NSNumber? {
            //....
            return nil
    }
}
```