# Swift: limit classes only supported protocol

Tags: swift

I want to implement method which took only classes supported protocols. For that purpose, I have defined a protocol:

```
protocol TestProt {
    func testMe() -> String
}
```

Let's do a class declaration:

```
class TestClass: TestProt {
    func testMe() -> String {
        return "test"
    }
}
```

But, how i can implement register class, for only classes supported TestProt?

```
class FabricaClass {
    // it is func take any classes :(
    func registerMe(context: MyContext, class: AnyClass) -> String {
    }
    // i want something like this =)
    // to the method took only classes supported protocols
    // but it don't work for swift...
    func registerMe(context: MyContext, class: AnyClass <TestProt>) -> String {
    }

}
```

UPD: Answer

```
protocol TestProt {
    static func testMe() -> String
}

class TestClass: TestProt {
    class func testMe() -> String {
        return "test"
    }
}

class MyContext {
}

class FactoryClass {
    init<T: TestProt>(context: MyContext, regClass: T.Type) {
        regClass.testMe()
    }
}

let context = MyContext()
let factory = FactoryClass(context: context, regClass: TestClass.self)
```

thanks for [@dfri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4573247/dfri)

Comment: Worth looking http://stackoverflow.com/a/24051850/2710486

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include a generic type in your function and add a *type constraint* to this generic type, where the type constraint ensures that types making use of the function conform to the protocol used as type constraint. E.g.:

```
/* add :class keyword to constrain this protocol only
 to be conformable to by class types */
protocol ProtocolOnlyIntendedForClasses: class {
    func foo() -> String
    init() // to make use of metaType for initialization in generic function
}

class Foo: ProtocolOnlyIntendedForClasses {
    func foo() -> String {
        return "foo"
    }
    required init() { }
}

/* function taking class type objects that conforms
   to ProtocolOnlyIntendedForClasses */
func bar<T: ProtocolOnlyIntendedForClasses>(foo: T) -> String {
    return foo.foo()
}

/* as above, but making use of metatype representation
   of generic T rather than an instance of it */
func barWithMetaType<T: ProtocolOnlyIntendedForClasses>(fooMetaType: T.Type) -> String {

    // ..

    return fooMetaType.init().foo()
}

/* example usage */
let foo = Foo()
let baz = bar(foo)
let bax = barWithMetaType(Foo.self)
print(baz, bax) // foo foo
```

Where we've accessed the type of `T` as a metatype using `T.Type`.

Applied to your specific example:

```
// ...

class FabricaClass {

    // ...

    // as specified in comments, you want the class (meta)type,
    // rather than an instance of it
    func registerMe<T: TestProt>(context: MyContext, someMetaType: T.Type) -> String {

        // ...

        return someMetaType.init().testMe()
            // given that you added blueprint for 'init()' in protocol TestProt
    }

}
```

Note, however, that the use metatypes (`someMetaType` in `registerMe(..)` function above) is quite limited, and not equivalent to using a static (compile-time known) type.

---

For additional details, refer to

- [The Language Guide - Generics: Section Type Constraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html)
- [The Language Guide - Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html)
- [The Language Reference - Types: Section Metatypes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html)

Comment: No, i need get **Class** in method, not Instans

Comment: @EvGeniyIlyin Updated answer with _metatypes_ of type constrained generic rather than instances of type constrained generic.

Comment: @EvGeniyIlyin Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
func registerMe(context: MyContext, class: TestProt) -> String {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you really want it restricted to classes or whether you meant:

> how i can implement register class, for only *types* supported
>   TestProt?

Anyway if you want to restrict to classes see @dfri's reply. For the rest of the question there are two ways. There is the generic approach:

```
fund registerMe<T: TestProt>(context: MyContext, class:T) -> String {}
```

where T takes on the type that it is passed. For example if this method were to return a type of the same type as class (rather than a `String`), the compiler would know that a `TestClass` instance was being returned. But the other way:

```
func registerMe(context: MyContext, class:TestProt) -> String {}
```

you are casting to TestProt, so while the dynamicType will still be `TestClass` at runtime, there is no way for you to return the same type as was passed to the method. You can only send back the instance as an instance that conforms to TestProt. And then you'd need to cast back to the actual class.